# Stack Exchange API: Is there a way to post things?

Tags: support, asking-questions, api

It would be nice if there is a way to post questions via HTTP calls, like with [Facebook Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API). But it doesn't seem to be available. Is it?

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't post questions (yet) using the stack exchange API.
Since API2.1 it's possible to add/edit/delete comments to questions, but that's it:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/stack-exchange-api-v2-1/

[Announcing API version 1.1 and Roadmap](https://stackapps.com/questions/1999/announcing-api-version-1-1)